# REGEX to catch whitespace or comments

Tags: regex, comments

I'm trying to create a regex that will catch whitespace or comments (//).
The content of the comment is obviously unknown (can contain any character).
I want to allow any character **only** after a comment, otherwise - only whitespace.
I run this regex on a string that contains new-lines.
Any suggestions?

Example:

```
whitespace
// Unknown comment 123@#$~
whitespace
whitespace // another comment
whitespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ones you mentioned is all that you want to capture, then use this : `(\s*)(//(.*))*`

Comment: I'm not doing a line-by-line match. I want to catch the new-lines as well.

Comment: Just tested it, it matches new-lines too.